# Cannot open another HTML file from Django

Tags: python, html, django

I was trying to call one html file from another via Django.
I actually have no errors inside my project(It works). But when I am trying to call the second html file the page refreshes only. Here is my code, thanks:D. My projects name is information and the name of my app is basic.

basic.views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.



def index(request):
    return render(request,'basic/index.html')


def customer(request):
    return render(request,'basic/customer.html')
```

basic.urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from basic import views


app_name='basic'

urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('',views.customer,name='customer'),
]
```

information.urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from basic import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name="index"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('basic.urls'))
]
```

Comment: you have same url string in base.urls.py, isn't that weird ?

Comment: The two pants are the same, so it will always take the first one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have two `path`s that match exactly the same path. So that means each time you make a request with an empty path, the first one is used.

You should make use of non-overlapping paths, for example:

```
# basic/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from basic import views


app_name='basic'

urlpatterns=[
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('customer/', views.customer, name='customer'),
]
```

and in your `information/urls.py`:

```
# information/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from basic import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('basic/', include('basic.urls'))
]
```